# Fire Panel's Click event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I was looking for how to automatically fire a `Click` event for a `Panel`. I found code to do this for a `Button` and it is not the same.

My problem is: I am making an auto gallery generator and I want fire the event when you click the parent block which contains the id for the user. The problem is when I click the event the image and the label are before block, then if I click image or label I want that block is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class users
    Private Sub users_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' COMPROVE CONNECTION
        Try
            ' ESTABLISH CONNECTION TO SERVER
            conn = New DataBase(DbServer, DbName, DbUser, Password)
            ' PICK UP DATA FROM USERS 
            Dim DataTable As New DataTable
            DataTable = conn.ConsultSql("SELECT `id_user`,`full_name`,`img` FROM `user` WHERE `user_type` = 1")
            ' PRINT PHARMACIST
            Dim b As Integer = 0
            While b < DataTable.Rows.Count
                Dim RowData As DataRow = DataTable.Rows(b)
                PrintUsers(RowData)
                b += 1
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió el siguiente error: " & ex.Message, "Error al loguearse", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintUsers(ByVal RowData As DataRow)
        Dim iNumber As String
        Console.WriteLine(RowData("full_name"))
        iNumber = RowData("full_name")
        ' GENERATE ID 
        Dim oPaneldId As New Panel
        oPaneldId.Name = RowData("id_user")
        ' GENERATE TEXT NAME 
        Dim oTextField As New Label
        oTextField.Name = "name" & iNumber
        oTextField.Text = iNumber
        ' GENEREATE PHOTO
        Dim oPictureBox As New PictureBox
        oPictureBox.Name = "img" & iNumber
        Dim MyWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        'BYTE ARRAY HOLDS THE DATA
        Dim ImageInBytes() As Byte = MyWebClient.DownloadData(RowData("img"))
        'CREATE A MEMORY STREAM USING THE BYTES
        Dim ImageStream As New IO.MemoryStream(ImageInBytes)
        'CREATE A BITMAP FROM THE MEMORY STREAM
        oPictureBox.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImageStream)
        oPictureBox.Size = New Size(100, 130)
        ' ADDING TO THE BODY
        oPaneldId.Controls.Add(oTextField)
        oPaneldId.Controls.Add(oPictureBox)
        AddHandler oPaneldId.Click, AddressOf Me.SelectUser
        AddHandler oPictureBox.Click, AddressOf Me.ClickFather
        AddHandler oTextField.Click, AddressOf Me.ClickFather
        body.Controls.Add(oPaneldId)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SelectUser()
        Console.WriteLine("Funciona")
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClickFather(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine(sender.GetType.Name)
        Console.WriteLine(sender.parent.Name)
        sender.parent.click
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your wording is confusing about the exact problem. First, this looks like a great time to make a `UserControl`, that encapsulates all those controls. Here you can organize the logic of what this control does. Then you just add a new `UserControl` and set some properties - like the user id, instead of creating several controls and wiring them up. The click events can be handled internally and maybe easier to control here.

Answer (score 0):

Add the click event handlers for the other controls in the panel to the same event handler you use for the panel`s click event. So your code would change to

```
AddHandler oPaneldId.Click, AddressOf Me.SelectUser
AddHandler oPictureBox.Click, AddressOf Me.SelectUser
AddHandler oTextField.Click, AddressOf Me.SelectUser
```

Comment: The problem of that is need to comprove if is a picture or label and that is not clean code. But speaking with one partner I see the light for do what i need directly. But ty for the answer :D

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "comprove", but you can tell which of the 3 controls was clicked by checking the sender parameter.